# In Ember.js, how should I name and arrange template files (.HBS) for nested routes?

Tags: templates, ember.js

I'm trying to use nested routes.  Here's my router.js:

```
App.Router.map(function
 () {
  // Add your routes here
  this.resource('notifications', { path: '/notifications' });
  this.resource('notification', { path: '/notifications/:notification_id' }, function() {
    this.route('edit');
  });
});
```

I'm using external Handelbars templates, i.e., .HBS files.  However, all of the examples I've seen for templates using nested routes use inline templates and have names like `notifications/edit`.  Can't I use .HBS files with nested routes?  If so, how would I name them?

Comment: Which build system are you using? Are you using `ember-cli`?

Comment: No.  I'm using Yeoman's Ember.js generator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using 'Yeoman's Ember.js generator', you can put it in folder.

```
notifications
 |- edit.hbs
```

The 'notifications/edit' will be contained in compiled-templates.js.